# How to add custom item to left CMS menu and manage model and extra fields? Similar to ModelAdmin?

Tags: silverstripe

Is it possible to have a Model Admin type setup, where there is a tab on the left menu e.g `Staff Members`, and on the right instead of just displaying a grid and managing a model, I want to have fields that sit above the grid and be able to save data to them...

Essentially working exactly the same as how you would do it on a page, but instead in its own tab on the sidebar etc?

**Picture of what I am trying to achieve** (Photoshopped)

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You'll have to create your own subclass of `LeftAndMain` and implement your Form by overriding `getEditForm`.

Say you named your new `LeftAndMain` subclass `StaffAdmin`, then you can add it to the CMS menu by adding this to your `_config.php` file:

```
CMSMenu::add_menu_item('StaffAdmin', 'Staff Admin', 'staffadmin', 'StaffAdmin');
```

Comment: Still haven't managed to achieve what I wanted here. Are you able to update you answer with a more thorough example. Essentially I want to create another 'SiteConfig', where you can add fields, display dataobjects and tabs etc